# Tris game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I've just started to code in JS, so I'm trying some classical exercises. 
Now I'm doing a simple *tris* game, but I have some problem with the victory check function that I posted here. Any ideas?

```js
function controllo() {
  var con = 0;

  if (tab['usx'] == tab['uc'] == tab['udx'] == 'X' || 
      tab['usx'] == tab['uc'] == tab['udx'] == 'O' ) //Orizzontali
    con = 1;
  else if (tab['csx'] == tab['cc'] == tab['cdx'] == 'X' ||
           tab['csx'] == tab['cc'] == tab['cdx'] == 'O')
    con = 1;
  else if (tab['dsx'] == tab['dc'] == tab['ddx'] == 'X' || 
           tab['dsx'] == tab['dc'] == tab['ddx'] == 'O')
    con = 1;
  else if (tab['usx'] == tab['cc'] == tab['ddx'] == "X" || 
           tab['usx'] == tab['cc'] == tab['ddx'] == "O") //Diagonali
    con = 1;
  else if (tab['udx'] == tab['cc'] == tab['dsx'] == 'X' || 
           tab['udx'] == tab['cc'] == tab['dsx'] == 'O')
    con = 1;
  else if (tab['udx'] == tab['cdx'] == tab['ddx'] == 'X' || 
           tab['udx'] == tab['cdx'] == tab['ddx'] == 'O') //Verticali
    con = 1;
  else if (tab['uc'] == tab['cc'] == tab['dc'] == 'X' || 
           tab['uc'] == tab['cc'] == tab['dc'] == 'O')
    con = 1;
  else if (tab['udx'] == tab['cdx'] == tab['ddx'] == 'X' || 
           tab['udx'] == tab['cdx'] == tab['ddx'] == 'O')
    con = 1;

  return (con);
}
```

`tab` is a global array and `con` is a local flag. "X" and "O" mean the 2 different players. The problem is that all the conditions are always false.

Comment: One problem is that `tab['usx']==tab['uc']==tab['udx']=='X'` doesn't work as you are expecting. It should be `tab['usx']=='X' && tab['uc']=='X' && tab['udx']=='X'`.

Comment: To demonstrate what @GOTO0 said: `"x"=="x"=="x"` evaluates to `false` but `"x"=="x"==true` evaluates to `true` - that's not what you want.

Comment: Too much wrong with this, and this kind of question doesn't belong in this forum

Answer (score 0):

See [this implementation](https://github.com/botika/ng2-tictactoe/blob/master/src/app/components/tictactoe/services/board.manager.ts)
In the first place you create a constant with the possible victories

```
var LINES = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
];
```

That you can use as in the implementation to count the X or O and if there are three it has won. The rest of the implementation I leave it to you. Is like [this](https://github.com/botika/ng2-tictactoe/blob/master/src/app/components/tictactoe/services/board.manager.ts#L38)